# wpf datagrid: Make cell Editable and non-Editable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with 2 columns one is DataGridComboBox namely 'Serial No' column and other is DataGridTextColumn namely 'Qty' .The DataGridComboBox column may or not having values in it.If the combobox has values then the user can select one value from it then the qty column become uneditable (readonly) and set 1 as default qty other wise it become editable cell ,Hence the user can enter any qty on it.How do I made the Qty column editable and non editable based on the value selection from combobox ?

Comment: Please post some code, To know what u have tried.

Answer (score 0):

you can try some thing like this

```
  <Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding A}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Choose" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfValues}" SelectedValue="{Binding Selected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Selected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="{Binding ValueAvalible}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid
```

In the Cell Demplate as of now i have put only TextBox and bound ValueAvalible to readonly Property. You can also have both label and TextBox and you can bind ValueAvalible  to visiblity of label and TextBox and. You can hide the text show the label if value is available. If no value is there in the comboBox you can hide label and show the textBox which will give a better user experience like below

```
<StackPanel>
     <Label Content="{Binding Selected}" Visibility="{Binding ValueAvalible, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=booleanToVisiblity}}"/>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Selected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Visibility="{Binding ValueAvalible, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=invertedBooleanToVisiblity}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In your viewModel

```
class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Values> A
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        A = new ObservableCollection<Values>();
        Values vv = new Values();
        vv.ListOfValues = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        vv.ListOfValues.Add("1");
        vv.ListOfValues.Add("2");
        vv.Selected = vv.ListOfValues[0];
        vv.ValueAvalible = true;
        A.Add(vv);
        A.Add(new Values());
    }
}

public class Values : NotifiyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> ListOfValues
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    private string selectedValue;
    public string Selected
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedValue;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedValue = value;
            Notify("Selected");
        }
    }

    public bool ValueAvalible
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}

public class NotifiyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
}
```